# coveragerc file ignores classes with similar names

Tags: python-3.x, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I'm running a coverage report in python and i created a .coveragerc file.  I have two classes for example:

```
class LinearRegression
class LinearRegressionMLE
```

when i instruct the coverage report to ignore LinearRegression, it ignores LinearRegressionMLE as well.  Is there anyway i can instruct it to ignore only LinearRegression while keeping LinearRegressionMLE?

my .coveragerc file:

```
# .coveragerc to control coverage
[report]
skip_empty = true
omit = 
    __init__.py

exclude_also =
    def __repr__
    @(abc\.)?abstractmethod
    RegressionDiagnostics
    LinearRegression

[html]
directory = tests/coverage_report_html
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok, i figured it out.
\bLinearRegression\b for exact match